# How to execute Hadoop Job written in Java on Hadoop Environment

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have class files loaded on to Hadoop file system.And also i have loaded input file to hdfs.
When I run class file through hadoop command in terminal i get Class not found error.
E.G.:
I have HDFS contents as 
    WordCount.class
    WordCountMapper.class
    WordCOuntReducer.class
    SampleInpujt.txt

Can Some one correct me where i am doing wrong.Or is this can be done in real.

Comment: Why are you running a class file you should be running a jar file??

Comment: And also the `Jar` file must be on local file system and not on HDFS as I know.

Comment: Please, specify which command exactly you are typing and what is the path of the files in this command

Answer (score 0):

Below is the commandline we use for running a Java mapreduce job on our 4-node Hadoop-2.2.0 cluster daily and it works fine. We run it from the namenode but any machine in the cluster should work fine.

```
hadoop jar ~/..path../mr_orchestrate/target/mr-orchestrate-1.0.jar com.rr.ap.orchestrate.MROrchestrate /user/hduser/in/Sample_15Feb2014.txt /user/hduser/out/out15Feb2014
```

You may need the "-libjars" option to add other library paths.